# Symfony Validator not using cache

Tags: symfony, validation, caching

I have symfony 5.2.3 project with a bunch of slow validation unit tests. I want validation constraints mapping to be cached.

Following docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#reference-validation-cache I have my validator.yaml as following (I have dumped it with cli, it is actually set to this):

```
framework:
validation:
    enabled: true
    email_validation_mode: html5
    cache: cache.default_redis_provider
```

and cache.yaml:

```
framework:
cache:
    app: cache.adapter.filesystem
    default_redis_provider: '%env(REDIS_CACHE_URL)%'
```

But cache is not being written in my redis. I dig in and find out that *Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Factory\LazyLoadingMetadataFactory* is being used for this. So I put some debug there and see that it is getting $cache = null from DI. I override it manually with

```
$cache = new RedisAdapter(new Client('redis://redis:6379?database=1'));
```

and my tests are working fast and cache is written and read.

What is going on? Does this validation.cache option even work? I can put any nonsence there and it wont even throw an error

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your complete configuration, but have to set the value of REDIS_CACHE_URL in '.env' file.